# An inventory database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I need to make an inventory db and I came up with the following:

[image]

Both STRUCTURE's and CONTAINER's PKs are also FKs to PLACE's PK. PLACE also has a PARENTID column so I can put a container inside a container and inside a structure.

So an INV_ITEM can be stored either in a structure or a container, and a container can be placed in another container and in a structure with the recursive relationship.

The same with EQUIPMENT. I can store it either in a structure by itself or in a container.

The problem is that I could also store a piece of equipment, a container or an inventory item in an equipment that's not designated as a container. For example, a car and a wrench are both EQUIPMENT, and a wrench can be stored in a car or in a container inside a car. How do I solve this?

**Update** 
More details 
STRUCTURE: a building with various uses. Can be a warehouse, a plant, a shed etc. 
CONTAINER: a more specific location used for storage that resides in a structure. Can be a physical item like a bin or a pallet, but also just a location, like "drawer 3". If it's a physical item that has the sole purpose of storing things, it's a container, not equipment. 
EQUIPMENT: tools used by the company. A car, a wrench, a forklift. Not for sale. Can be stored either in a structure OR a container. Has a "serial" column to uniquely identify it. 
INV_ITEM: A product, anything that the company routinely buys or sells. Stock. For example shirts, candlesticks, sunglasses, screws. It also includes fuel for company's equipment. Can be stored either in a structure OR a container. Has a "quantity on hand" column. 
PLACE: base table that solves the exclusive arc problem between STRUCTURE and CONTAINER and allows us to put a container in a structure.

Comment: your text does not seem to match your picture.  is a CAR a PLACE? does not seem like it is - so your issue should not come up based on the image.

Comment: That's the thing, a car belongs in the EQUIPMENT table. But what if you want to store a wrench in it, which is also in the EQUIPMENT table? I could make EQUIPMENT a PLACE, but that wouldn't make sense for the wrench and most of the other equipment.

Comment: What is the difference between an inventory item and a piece of equipment? In an inventory database, I would expect everything in it to be either inventory or the stuff needed to maintain (store/transport) the inventory. When I see "equipment," I think of shelving, forklifts, bins, trucks, cargo ships, etc. So what is it about a car that makes it equipment and not just another inventory item?

Comment: An inventory item is the physical instance of a PRODUCT. The EQUIPMENT table contains just that, company equipment: cars, wrenches, forklifts etc - distinct fixed assets that are not associated with a product. A car is EQUIPMENT if it is used by the company in its daily tasks, it is an inventory item if the company sells cars.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

- Form follows function, so if a car can also be a container then your schema must also show that. But before you do, is the idea of a wrench inside a car your own hypothetical condition? Because normally, one inventory item cannot be placed inside a second inventory item unless it is a part of that item, no matter how much logistical sense it may make to do so. For example, the spare tire. But in that situation, the spare tire is not a separate item, it is part of the car.
- Also, by placing the PARENTID in Place, you are also saying you can put a structure inside a structure inside a container. Is that what you want?

So one change you may want to consider is moving PARENTID to Container. And, unless this is a homework assignment and it is part of the assignment, don't worry about putting items into other items. That is generally not a real-life condition.

Comment: I didn't had a problem with my design until I thought of this special case where it makes sense to store an EQUIPMENT inside another EQUIPMENT. It makes sense to store the wrench inside the car and it's a real life situation. I don't want to store the wrench in a structure, I want it in my car. And what if I put the wrench in a container in the car?

Comment: Yes, I can put a structure inside a structure inside a container. Kind of funny, isn't it? But if I move the PARENTID to CONTAINER, I can't put a container inside a structure. Both STRUCTURE's and CONTAINER's PKs are also FKs to PLACE's PK. PLACE exists because there is an exclusive arc between STRUCTURE and CONTAINER - an INV_ITEM or an EQUIPMENT can be stored either in a structure or in a container. And apparently an EQUIPMENT can be stored in another EQUIPMENT, and this is where I got stuck.

Comment: I think at this point you have to be more clear in your definitions. What is a structure and what is a container? How are they similar and how different? What is an inventory item and what is a piece of equipment? Compare and contrast. Right now these are just words. To model "things" we have to know the characteristics of those things. Give us some.